# Capybara / Ruby - Trying to return all tags and html attributes

Tags: ruby, rspec, automated-tests, capybara

Trying to return all  tags with all  attribute values, however just some of them is being returned.

```
describe 'Html', :html do
  before(:each) do
    visit 'https://www2.losango.com.br/'
  end

  it 'Html' do
    html = page.all('img').map { |img| img['alt'] }
    print html
  end
end
```

When I open the url "https://www2.losango.com.br/" I will find lots of img alt="", however when I run it I got the result:

```
Losango - Conte com a gente
Losango - Conte com a gente
Empréstimo Pessoal Losango
Crediário Losango
Seguros Losango
Seguros Losango
Simulador de Crédito ideal
Cartão de Crédito Losango
Losango - Conte com a gente
```

The following - img alt="Empréstimo com taxa a partir de 3.99% a.m" - is not being returned. Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="banner__img">
          <figure>
            <img src="https://www2.losango.com.br/assets/imagens/pws/banner-emprestimo.jpg" alt="Empréstimo com taxa a partir de 3.99% a.m">
          </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Be more specific. What is the *exact* expected output and what is the *exact* actual output?

Comment: Hi, I would like to see all tags <img alt=""> ..all of them, with my current code just some are being displayed.

Comment: for example, the following html is not being displayed:                                                                                                                             
<img src="https://www2.losango.com.br/assets/imagens/pws/banner-emprestimo.jpg" alt="Empréstimo com taxa a partir de 3.99% a.m">

Comment: The word *exact* means that you should include in your post the output of your test when you run it and then show line by line what is missing from the output that you expect to find. Don’t make people write an app and include a test and run the test to see what output *we* get just so we can *guess* what output you are getting, and don’t make us *guess* at what you expect us to see.

Comment: got it, sorry @anothermh, Im new here :) .. I'll edit it.. thank you

Comment: Question updated ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Capybara only finds elements that are visible on the page. The element you're specifically asking about isn't being returned because it's not visible on the page.  If you want to get all the matching elements (visible and non-visible) you can tell `all` to ignore visibility checking by changing to

```
html = page.all('img', visible: false).map { |img| img['alt'] }
```